# Counting letters in R

Tags: regex, r, character, string-matching

I have pages of text and I want to find the start and end positions of a certain word appearing in the text:

```
<body> I need to find the position of a **certain** word from a lot of text.</body>
```

For example here certain (without the **) starts at position 34 and ends at 40. Also numbers and punctuation are to be counted.

How could I do this in R? The text is in xml-format.

Comment: Many efficient answers, but I'm afraid the text is so long it doesn't fit into the vector A nor object x... Any ideas on how to tackle this besides split the text?

Comment: How long is your text, and approximately how many times might the target word show up?

Comment: One of them is 625 words 6000+ letter/spaces. When I delete it to just over 4000 letters/spaces it fits into the vector/object. The searched words are very sparse so the word usually only appears once in the text.

Comment: Can you clarify?  If you parse the xml document and extract the text strings, and then create a vector of those strings, why won't the answer find the target word start and end position(s) in the vector?  It doesn't seem your text sizes (the strings) are all that large.

Comment: This question reminds me of the example given in this discussion of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm pretty sure that's what we have here.

Comment: I have extracted the text from the xml (copy+paste for now) and I can get the start and end positions as long as the text is not too long (at least I suspect this is the reason since it works when I delete end part of the text). When I try with all the text, R-Studio prints a plus (+) as the last row, as if waiting for some parameter ie for the function to continue...  On the other hand, when I delete the end of text so its around 4000 letters/spaces, then R-Studio does create the vector x,  and there is not a + but a > as the last row. So is there a maximum number of characters to a vector?

Answer (score 4):

Use `gregexpr`:

```
x <- "I need to find the position of a certain word from a lot of certain text,
which needs a certain text processing function."
gregexpr("certain", x, fixed = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 34 61 89
#attr(,"match.length")
#[1] 7 7 7
#attr(,"useBytes")
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

The `stringi` package has a very useful function:

```
x <- "I need to find the position of a certain word from a lot of certain text, which needs a certain text processing function."

> stringi::stri_locate_all_regex(str = x, "certain") # list of start and end locations for matches
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]    34  40
[2,]    61  67
[3,]    89  95
```

Comment: I guess `stri_locate_all_fixed` might be a bit faster

Comment: @akrun, thank you.  I rarely think about speed but your point is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package cwhmisc. You should bring your text into a vector

```
library(cwhmisc)

A<-("I need to find the position of a certain word from a lot of text")

cpos(A, "certain")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
> regexpr("a","sjnasd")
[1] 4
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

however this works for the first occurrence of the substring in the bigger string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stringr`'s `str_locate` function - note that this is just a wrapper around `base::regexpr`, but the name is much more memorable :-)

```
> require(stringr)
> x <- "I need to find the position of a certain word from a lot of text."
> str_locate(x, "certain")
     start end
[1,]    34  40
```